# Copy & Export Data from 'Find and Replace' box or searchbox using vba in excel

Tags: excel, vba, userform, search-box, find-all-references

Actually I dont have any spesific data to referred, only just wonder if it can be done to export the data  to another workbook (whether open or closed) by click on selected row in searchbox from active workbook.

Let's says, the data found in active workbook searchbox is in Row 7, then when click on it (in searchbox) so the data will be exported to another workbook. Not necessery to export all the data, maybe need it in Cell D7, F7 & K7 only to export.  And target workbook will filled with the exported data to B4(D7),  G8(F7) & L9(K7).

Can it be done using VBA codes? Maybe have to created Userform as a 'Find and Replace' box? Maybe there is another way can make it done? Thank you very much in advance if you accept this challenge and wish you good luck.

Post code here:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done using VBA. This can get you started.

**Example**

This example finds all cells in the range A1:A500 on worksheet one that contain the value 2, and changes it to 5.

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 
    Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
            c.Value = 5 
            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If 
End With
```

Look here for source and more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: Thank you Daghan! Based on the code, I am sure that your answer is how to find the value. The primary question is - how to export it to another workbook by clicking the row. Any idea?

Comment: Sure it's possible. You can create a button on your worksheet that does the following. Select entire row of the activecell (the cell acitivates when you find it using the find/replace dialogue), open destination workbook or a new workbook. Set a target range in the target workbook and set targetrow.value=sourcerow.value. You can google each step and try to come up with some code.

Comment: Export certian data to the target cells in other workbook? If you said so, then show me the code.

Comment: This is quite basic VBA. This forum is not meant for us to write your code, there are 100's of workbook to workbook tutorials and don't worry, its quite easy. [This is one of many guides](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-another-workbook/)

Comment: you didnt get the question here, do you Daghan? let me explain again..

Comment: **copy/export** data from **Find and Replace** by clicking on **selected result row** in searchbox.<< Hope this sentence is clear what I meant

Comment: As suggested by yourself, create a userform like the find and replace box. It is not possible to edit the functionality of the built-in find and replace. to answer your question: Yes it is possible in VBA

Comment: As suggested by yourself, create a userform like the find and replace box.<< already did and its working but I stuck on how to export the data by click on selected row result.

Comment: Sounds good eltigre :-)  Edit your post and add the code you have for exporting right now. I assume you are populating a listbox with the "search-results"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ListBox_Results_Click()
Dim strAddress As String
Dim strSheet As String
Dim strCell As String
Dim l As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long
Const sRESULTS As String = "Results Sheet" 
For l = 0 To ListBox_Results.ListCount
If ListBox_Results.Selected(l) = True Then
strAddress = ListBox_Results.List(l, 1)
strSheet = Replace(Mid(strAddress, 1, InStr(1, strAddress, "!") - 1), "'", "")
Worksheets(strSheet).Select
Worksheets(strSheet).Range(strAddress).Select
```

> ```
> With Worksheets(sRESULTS)
> lLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
> .Range("A" & lLastRow).Value = Worksheets(strSheet).Range(strAddress).Value
> .Range("B" & lLastRow).Value = strAddress
> .Range("C" & lLastRow).Value = Now
> ```

```
End With
GoTo EndLoop
End If
Next l
EndLoop:
End Sub
```

Comment: I belive that  start with 'With Worksheets(sRESULTS)' have to edit to change the result.